# React JS history.listen not firing after page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, history.js

I am listening to React history changes in my component like this:

```
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
  history.listen(() => { // do something here});
}, [history]);
```

It works as long as page is not reloaded. When i reload the page history.listen callback does not fire. Can anyone point out how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `history` point of view no action was fired after refresh. If you want to call the listener on mount, just call it directly in the `useEffect`:

```
const history = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
  const listener = () => { // do something here};
  history.listen(listener);
  listener();
}, [history]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Tell the entire story.

Comment: I am integrating a analytics API and i need o track the routes that user visits. So i am listing to history and whenever route changes is make send an event to analytics API. Problem is if i reload the page (or say user open the link to the page from an email) the history.listen call back does not execute.

Comment: My solution should work for you. Add the listener's code to your question.

Comment: While typing in code in my answer i caught the mistake. There was a missing dependency in useEffect. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `window.addEventListener` method to listen to the `popstate` event.

```js
const handleHistoryChange = () => {
  // do something here
}

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('popstate', handleHistoryChange);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('popstate', handleHistoryChange);
  };
}, []);
```